# VS2010 SP1 C++ STL string runtime behavior different between <string.h> and <string>

Tags: c++

Here is a simple demonstration of the discrepancy:

```
//if using <string> you can do cout << str
//if using <string.h> you must do cout << str.c_str() (else get runtime error)
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    char* pBuf;
    string str = "Hello World";

    //cout << str.c_str() << endl;
    cout << str << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

How can I force the runtime library to always allow cout << mystr (consistently, without needing to add mystring.c_str() ) ????

My application is mixed (both #include headers exist)....is the runtime confused?

Answer (score 6):

`string.h` is a *C* header file which corresponds to `<cstring>` in c++. You should include `<string>` which defines `std::string` and the needed `operator<<`. If you need the C string functions, include `<cstring>` and avoid `<string.h>`